# Add Win7 to 17.10 - different HDD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-7

I have an existing 17.10 installation. I have a second HDD that I want to put Win7 on. The machine doesn't have UEFI. Doing a fresh 17.10 installation isn't an option.

AFAIK, the problem comes down to getting the boot process right.

A) Does installing Win7 cover up the existing 17.10 boot installation? That is I can swap the HDD SATA cables long enough to install Win7 and put them back to the original setup; the Linux HDD becomes the boot HDD.

B) How do I set up a boot process that can be defaulted to Linux most of the time but be set to default to Win7 if needed?

C) I want to mount the Win7 HDD, in 17.10, as a data drive, and mount the Linux HDD as a data drive for Win7. The only need is to exchange files, etc. How do I handle the Linux side? I assume Win7 will "see" the Linux HDD and try to mount it.

Answer (score 1):

A) yes, Windows will overwrite grub. Remove the Ubuntu drive, install Windows, then replace the Ubuntu drive as the first HDD, should preserve grub. Note: grub will need to be updated to get the windows entry in the boot menu.

C) Windows can not read Linux partitions without third party software (if available). The preferred method to share files is to make a partitions formated ntfs that can be mounted to both OSs. Note: hibernation must be turned off to share partitions, since writing to a hibernated partition from another OS can cause file corruption when the hibernated system is restarted.

B) I believe there is a way to tell grub to boot windows next from the command line, but I do not know it.

Comment: I believe Grub Customizer can be used for B). Should be easier than manually editing Grub.

Comment: A) OK, not swapping cables is a Bad Idea B) Grub Customizer is now installed - I "only" need to figure out how to use it and not wipe my system... C) Doh... I should know better than that. I'll leave everything alone and not try to get the two OS' to talk directly with each other. It's that or change to ntfs and I'd rather not do that.